# Using something like ngRepeat in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to populate a drop-down list with data from an array. The code below is something I would do if I was working with angularJS. I want to know if there is a way to do this in javascript or somehow allow ng-options to work here.

```
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var city = ["NewYork", "Chicago", "Florida"];

  var contentString = 
      `<div class="dropdown">
   <select>
     <option ng-options="item for item in ${city}">{{item}}</option>
   </select>
</div>`;

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)',
//    zIndex: Math.round(myLatlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/spdmu6we/5/

Comment: Here is a [JavaScript solution](https://jsfiddle.net/d75k0Lcg/)

Comment: @RandyCasburn this works but is there a way to implement this with the way I had it, without having to put the HTML in the HTML section and having the content string variable there.

Comment: Yes, you have two options: 1. Use string parsing to build up a string of HTML and then pass that as your content 2. Parse the string you have into a DOM Node and use the code I provided.

Comment: Here's the string concatenation solution: https://jsfiddle.net/1wrmde9y/

Comment: Yeah this works, you can put this as the answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comment, you prefer to do this without and HTML `'.

So, you have two options: 1. Use string parsing to build up a string of HTML and then pass that as your content 2. Parse the string you have into a DOM Node and use the code I provided.

This replaces the GMap stuff with generic code. You will still be able to use the code related to the DOM.

Here is a solution:

```js
var city = ["NewYork", "Chicago", "Florida"];
const pre = '<div class="dropdown"><select>';
const post = '</select></div>';
let options = '';
city.forEach(city => {
  let o = `<option value=${city}>${city}</option>`;
  options += o;
});
content = pre + options + post;

var infowindow = document.createElement('div');
infowindow.innerHTML = content;
infowindow.style.display = 'none'

var marker = document.createElement('button');
marker.innerText = "Click me";

marker.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.body.appendChild(infowindow);
  infowindow.style.display='block';
});
document.body.appendChild(marker);
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The two typical ways of creating a lot of elements in javascript is either:

1. concat a long string of the elements together, like `"<option>Banana</option><option>Apple</option>"` and then use .innerHTML on the parent `select`
2. use javascript to create each node independantly like `document.createElement("OPTION")` and `.appendChild` it.

There's performance implications on each.  But native javascript doesn't do that kind of templating.

Comment: Well I tried the second option and I keep getting a null error https://jsfiddle.net/wegs6okb/1/

Comment: That's because you don't have a select element in the HTML, yet you are trying to access it.